# Can't get hasmany tables in laravel 5.1 eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am having problem in getting the `hasmany` relationship data in Laravel eloquent.

AModel hasmany BModel
AModel hasmany CModel

AModel has function:

```
Public function bmodels(){
    return hasMany('BModel');
}

Public function cmodels(){
    return hasMany('CModel');
}
```

BModel has function:

```
Public function bmodels(){
    return belongsTo('AModel', amodel_id);
}
```

CModel has function:

```
Public function cmodels(){
    return belongsTo('AModel',amodel_id);
}
```

Now i am trying to get it like this

```
$amodels = AModel::with('bmodels','cmodels')
        ->where('status_id','2200')
        ->whereIn('eventstatus_id',['1','2'])
        ->get();
```

and now i want to test this in the for loop.

```
foreach($amodels as $amodel){
    $bmodels = $model->bmodels();
    if ($amodel && $amodel->end < Carbon::now()){
        foreach ($bmodels as $bmodel){
            $cmodels = $amodel->cmodels();
            foreach($cmodels as $cmodel){
                if ($bmodel->id !== $cmodel->reservation_id || $cmodel->reservation_id != null ){
                    array_push($reservation_needed_to_enter,$bmodel->id);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to access those models jst write $amodel->bmodels instead of $amodel->bmodels() in your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks works now

Comment: can you accept it as answer?then i will post an answer

Comment: how can i accept i cant see any answer

Comment: ok I'm posting it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make changes in your **Models**, use `$this` to use `belongsTo` and `hasMany`,like

```
public function bmodels(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AModel','amodel_id');
}
public function bmodels(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\BModel');
}
```

Just Edited your `foreach loop`, use `$amodel->bmodels` instead of `$amodel->bmodels()`

```
 foreach($amodels as $amodel){
        $bmodels = $amodel->bmodels;
        if ($amodel && $amodel->end < Carbon::now()){
            foreach ($bmodels as $bmodel){
                $cmodels = $amodel->cmodels;
                foreach($cmodels as $cmodel){
                    if ($bmodel->id !== $cmodel->reservation_id || $cmodel->reservation_id != null ){
                        array_push($reservation_needed_to_enter,$bmodel->id);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your models are stored at the default directory you should probably do this instead:

```
public function bmodels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BModel');
}
```

Do you have a function in `AModel` named `cmodels` if not this could be the problem. Because you are trying to get `AModel::with('bmodels','cmodels')` but if one of those isn't there it is not going to work.

And this `if ($amodel && $amodel->end < Carbon::now()){` doesn't make sense to me. Because `$amodel` will alwasy be an instance of `Eloquent\Model` and never false or whatever you are trying to check there. But maybe it has a purpose..

How to accces your `BModel` in your `.blade` file:

```
@foreach($aModel->bmodels() as $bModel)
   {{$bModel->id}}
@endforeach()
```

Comment: when i try to get the properties of hasmany model, get error. for instance if i do like amodel->bmodels->id get error i am doing it inside the foreach loop

Comment: Because bmodels is an HasMany relationship this won't work. Try something like i do in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace this two functions in your `AModel`

```
Public function bmodels(){
    return hasMany('BModel');
}

Public function cmodels(){
    return hasMany('CModel');
}
```

with

```
public function bmodels(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\BModel');
}

public function cmodels(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CModel');
}
```

and these functions in `BMOdel` and `CModel` as

```
public function bmodels(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AModel','amodel_id');
}

public function cmodels(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AModel','amodel_id');
}
```

Comment: No its not getting i dont understand what is the prpoblem here

Comment: Actually all models are in same namesapce, you should give the model name with complete path and use `$this` object to refer the current object